# Airodump-ng doesn't capture handshake or sees any devices connected on Kali, but captures everything on Backtrack. How to fix it?

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng, driver, handshake, airodump-ng

I ran into a problem in using kali linux system.

Kali doesn't allow me to see any devices connected to certain spot or capture any handshakes, I know that it can capture them(and see connected devices) because I tried to use 'airodump' command on Backtrack and it all worked fine. However Backtrack is old and it doesn't get updated anymore, so I have to use Kali Linux.

Did anyone run into the same problem, and found solution for it? I am open to any suggestions.

I guess if I will be able to see devices connected, then I will be able to capture handshakes, and so on.

**Background**: My network adapter chipset is: Atheros AR242x/AR542x. I DO NOT RUN VM, I have Kali Linux installed natively on my computer.

Comment: What device is? I mean not the chipset (you already posted it)... I mean the brand and the model of the device. Everything sounds like a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no one is connected to the wifi spot right now.
(If you do see someone you can "deauth" him in order to get a handshake).
Try on your wifi and check if you do see anyone who is connected while you know someone really is.
Also maybe you're to faraway from the hotspot/this hotspot is on a crowded channel (there are many wifi's on the same channel nearby).

Comment: I did try to deauth my phone, and as I said it works on backtrack(it sees my phone and the handshake), but on kali it just doesn't see it.

Comment: @RaulAlkino Weird, sounds like the network card doesn't work properly in kali. are you even able to scan for wifi's nearby?

Comment: Yes, it finds all wifi's around my area but doesn't see any devices connected(even if I use 'deauth' to reconnect them)

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the "-w" tag? You should use it to write the handshake to a file.
Also the other reason you don't capture any handshakes is because:
1. No one authenticated to the target AP while you were sniffing from the air.
2. Not in range.
Try to Deauthenticate a client from the target AP.